# Re-deploying certificates after expiry in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-security

Certificates in my kubernetes are expired. What are the steps in redeploying certificates. After redployment pod health is affected. How do i overcome this?

```
[mdupaguntla@iacap067 K8S_HA_Setup_Post_RPM_Installation_With_RBAC]$ sudo kubectl logs elasticsearch-logging-0
+ export NODE_NAME=elasticsearch-logging-0
+ NODE_NAME=elasticsearch-logging-0
+ export NODE_MASTER=true
+ NODE_MASTER=true
+ export NODE_DATA=true
+ NODE_DATA=true
+ export HTTP_PORT=9200
+ HTTP_PORT=9200
+ export TRANSPORT_PORT=9300
+ TRANSPORT_PORT=9300
+ export MINIMUM_MASTER_NODES=2
+ MINIMUM_MASTER_NODES=2
+ chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /data
+ ./bin/elasticsearch_logging_discovery
F0323 07:18:25.043962       8 elasticsearch_logging_discovery.go:78] kube-system namespace doesn't exist: Unauthorized
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog.stacks(0xc4202b1200, 0xc42020a000, 0x77, 0x85)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:766 +0xcf
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog.(*loggingT).output(0x1a38100, 0xc400000003, 0xc4200ba2c0, 0x1994cf4, 0x22, 0x4e, 0x0)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:717 +0x322
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog.(*loggingT).printf(0x1a38100, 0x3, 0x121acfe, 0x1e, 0xc4206aff50, 0x2, 0x2)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:655 +0x14c
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog.Fatalf(0x121acfe, 0x1e, 0xc4206aff50, 0x2, 0x2)
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:1145 +0x67
main.main()
        /go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/es-image/elasticsearch_logging_dis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Certificates in my kubernetes are expired. What are the steps in redeploying certificates. After redployment pod health is affected. How do i overcome this?
>
> ...
>
> F0323 07:18:25.043962       8 elasticsearch_logging_discovery.go:78] kube-system namespace doesn't exist: Unauthorized

It seems you must have regenerated the private key for the certificates, rather that just issuing new certs using CSRs generated using the *existing* keys of the cluster.

If that is true, then you will need to do (at least) one of the following two things:

Dig the old private key files out of a backup, generate a CSR from them, re-issue the API certificates, and chalk this up to a valuable lesson not to delete private keys again without careful thought

Or:

Delete all the  [`serviceAccounts`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-multiple-service-accounts) named in any `Pod`'s `serviceAccountName`, for every namespace, followed by a deletion of those pods themselves to get their `volumeMount:`s rebound. Addition information is in [their admin guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/service-accounts-admin/).

If all goes well, the `ServiceAccountController` will recreate those `ServiceAccount` secrets, allowing those `Pod`s to start back up, and you are back in business.

The concrete steps to manage the X.509 certificates for a cluster are too numerous to fit into a single answer box, but that is the high level overview of what needs to happen.

Comment: Tried with first approach. Got solution for my problem. Thanks.

May i know the reason behind using the old private key's for generating new certificates?

Comment: _May i know the reason behind using the old private key's for generating new certificates_ because the private key represents the true contract between the apiserver and the rest of the cluster; the certificate is, as you saw, more "ephemeral" details like the `CN`, and expiry, etc. That process is exactly the same as how "normal" SSL renewals work, and for the same reason.

Comment: HI Matthew L Daniel can you please help me to solve this problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303819/rbac-error-in-kubernetes